# Regular expression with drools

Tags: regex, drools

I have a string with multiline as below.

```
rawMessage=sysUpTimeInstance-->0:0:00:05.00
snmpTrapOID.0-->linkDown.0.0
```

In the drools when portion i have written the condition as below.

```
rawMessage  matches "(?i).*linkDown(.|\n|\r)*"
```

but it is not working.Please provide me some pointers to handle multiline.

Answer (score 3):

Its not clear to me what you want to do/achieve. Your regex looks not wrong (I don't know the drools flavour and what you want to match).
In general `(.|\n|\r)*` is able to match any character including newlines. In your example there is no newline after "linkDown", so what should it match there?

Maybe you need to double escape (I don't know for drools) like this: `(.|\\n|\\r)*`.

Another possibility is to use the singleline modifer `s` (Again, I don't know if drools supports this modifier). This makes the `.` match also newline characters, could then look something like this

```
rawMessage  matches "(?i)(?s).*linkDown.*"
```

or if it should only match multiline from "linkdown" on

```
rawMessage  matches "(?i).*linkDown(?s).*"
```

Comment: i tried the approach rawMessage  matches "(?i)(?s).*linkDown.*".Its working for me.Thanks a lot stema

Comment: You are welcome. Its good practice at SO to accept an answer if it solved a problem, see [here, how-does-accepting-an-answer-work](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Answer (score 0):

Drools uses standard java regular expressions. As the previous answer mention, your expression looks wrong. And yes, you need to double escape special chars like you would do in java. Just check the javadoc for the Pattern class in the java API.

Comment: I added double escpace.still no luck.I am using drools5.